# Download files from remote machine using nodejs and rest api

Tags: node.js

I am using node js, rest API. I want to download files from remote machine where tomcat is running on that machine. Kindly help me how to send a request and response back to node js.

Answer (score 0):

In nodeJs response provide download method.

```
app.post('/download', function(req, res){
  var file = __dirname + '/list.csv';
  res.download(file);
});
```

Other manual way:

```
app.post('/download', function(req, res){



        // console.log('dir ', __dirname);
        var file = __dirname + '/list.csv';
        var filename = path.basename(file);
        var mimetype = mime.lookup(file);

        res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=' + filename);
        res.setHeader('Content-type', mimetype);
        console.log("shubham batra = " +mimetype);
        var filestream = fs.createReadStream(file);
        filestream.pipe(res);
        //res.redirect('/other-link');

});
```

Comment: Hi, Through rest api i am getting response , when i try to send the repsonse to front end, its displaying in encoded way. how can i display download option